# Backbone: Id not being set to model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have tried the following to set an id to my model:

```
var globalCounter = 1;

var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.id = globalCounter;
        globalCounter += 1;
    }
});

myModel = new Model();
console.log(myMode.get('id')); // prints undefined
```

How can I set an id to my models?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the [`set()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) function instead (http://jsbin.com/agosub/1/);

```
var globalCounter = 1;

var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.set('id', globalCounter);
        globalCounter += 1;
    }
});

myModel = new Model();
console.log(myModel.get('id')); // prints 1
```

Answer (score 7):

You must use :

```
this.set('id', globalCounter);
```

instead of `this.id = globalCounter;`

You are adding the id value to the Model object, but you want to add it to **Model.attributes** object. And that what is doing Model.set() method.

`model.set("key", value)` will put the value in `model.attributes.key;`

`model.get("key")` will return the value inside `model.attributes.key`

This is a little weird for new comers to Backbone, but it's a major (and easy) point to get. It's designed so that using `model.set(...)` will fire change events you can easily catch to update your views.

### Backbone and ES6 Update :

The Backbone attribute object is outdates by ES6 getters and setters. Theses functions can overwrite the standard access.

Warning : this is pseudo-code that may be one day used with ES6 !

```
class MyModel extends Backbone.Model{

    get id(){ return this.attributes.id; }
    set id(id){ this.attributes.id = id; }

}
```

This would allow to write :

```
let myModel = new Model();
myModel.id = 13; // will use myModel.id(13)
console.log (myModel.id); // will show myModel.id()
```

As of today, this is only a dream of a Backbone 2. After basic searches, I've seen nothing about that coming.

Comment: Thanks, I've just added some more.